# Why can't 64-bit Windows unwind user-kernel-user exceptions?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows64, structured-exception, windows-appcompat-platform

Why can't 64-bit Windows unwind the stack during an exception, if the stack crosses the kernel boundary - when 32-bit Windows can?

The context of this entire question comes from:

[The case of the disappearing OnLoad exception – user-mode callback exceptions in x64](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)

### Background

In 32-bit Windows, if i throw an exception in my *user mode* code, that was called back from *kernel mode* code, that was called from my *user mode* code, e.g:

```
User mode                     Kernel Mode
------------------            -------------------
CreateWindow(...);   ------>  NtCreateWindow(...)
                                   |
WindowProc   <---------------------+
```

the Structured Exception Handling (SEH) in Windows can unwind the stack, unwinding back through kernel mode, back into my user code, where i can handle the exception and i see a valid stack trace.

### But not in 64-bit Windows

64-bit editions of Windows cannot do this:

> For complicated reasons, we **cannot propagate the exception back on 64-bit operating systems** (amd64 and IA64). This has been the case ever since the first 64-bit release of Server 2003. On x86, this isn’t the case – the exception gets propagated through the kernel boundary and would end up walking the frames back

And since there's no way to walk back a reliable stack trace in this case, the had to make a decision: let you see the non-nonsensical exception, or hide it altogether:

> The kernel architects at the time decided to take the conservative AppCompat-friendly approach – hide the exception, and hope for the best.

The article goes on to talk about how this was how all 64-bit Windows operating systems behaved:

- Windows XP 64-bit
- Windows Server 2003 64-bit
- Windows Vista 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008 64-bit

But starting with Windows 7 (and Windows Server 2008), the architects changed their minds - sort of. For ***only*** 64-bit applications (not 32-bit applications), they would (by default) **stop** suppressing these user-kernel-user exceptions. So, by default, on:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Windows Server 2008

all 64-bit applications will *see* these exceptions, where they never used to see them.

> In Windows 7, when a *native x64* application crashes in this fashion, the [Program Compatibility Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx) is notified. If the application doesn’t have a [Windows 7 Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711%28VS.85%29.aspx), we show a dialog telling you that PCA has applied an [Application Compatibility shim](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644%28WS.10%29.aspx). What does this mean? This means, that the next time you run your application, Windows will emulate the Server 2003 behavior and make the exception disappear. Keep in mind, that PCA doesn’t exist on Server 2008 R2, so this advice doesn’t apply.

### So the question

The question is *why* is 64-bit Windows unable to unwind a stack back through a kernel transition, *while 32-bit editions of Windows can?*

The only hint is:

> For complicated reasons, we **cannot propagate the exception back on 64-bit operating systems** (amd64 and IA64).

The hint is *it's complicated*.

i may not understand the explanation, as i'm not an operating system developer - but i'd like a shot at  knowing why.

---

### Update: Hotfix to stop suppressing 32-bit apps

Microsoft has released [a *hotfix* enables 32-bit applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038) to also no longer have the exceptions suppressed:

> ### KB976038: Exceptions that are thrown from an application that runs in a 64-bit version of Windows are ignored
>
> - An exception that is thrown in a callback routine runs in the user mode.
>
> In this scenario, this exception does not cause the application to crash. Instead, the application enters into an inconsistent state. Then, the application throws a different exception and crashes.
>
> A user mode callback function is typically an application-defined function that is called by a kernel mode component. Examples of user mode callback functions are Windows procedures and hook procedures. These functions are called by Windows to process Windows messages or to process Windows hook events.

The hotfix then lets you stop Windows from eating the exceptions globally:

> ```
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
> DisableUserModeCallbackFilter: DWORD = 1
> ```

or per-application:

> ```
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\Notepad.exe
> DisableUserModeCallbackFilter: DWORD = 1
> ```

The behavior was also documented on XP and Server 2003 in KB973460:

- [Exceptions that are thrown from a 64-bit application that is running in the 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2003 or of Windows XP Professional are silently ignored](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973460)

---

### A hint

i found another hint when investigating using xperf to capture stack traces on 64-bit Windows:

### [Stack Walking in Xperf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pigscanfly/archive/2009/08/06/stack-walking-in-xperf.aspx)

> **Disable Paging Executive**
>
> In order for tracing to work on 64-bit Windows you need to set the **DisablePagingExecutive** registry key. This tells the operating system not to page kernel mode drivers and system code to disk, which is a prerequisite for getting 64-bit call stacks using xperf, because 64-bit stack walking depends on metadata in the executable images, and in some situations the xperf **stack walk code is not allowed to touch paged out pages**. Running the following command from an elevated command prompt will set this registry key for you.
>
> ```
>  REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" -v 
>  DisablePagingExecutive -d 0x1 -t REG_DWORD -f
> ```
>
> After setting this registry key you will need to reboot your system before you can record call stacks. Having this flag set means that the Windows kernel locks more pages into RAM, so this will probably consume about 10 MB of additional physical memory.

This gives the impression that in 64-bit Windows (and only in 64-bit Windows), you are not allowed to walk kernel stacks because there might be pages out on disk.

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, but if I had to guess I'd say it's theoretically possible but made inconvenient by some component's data structure, either an OS component or perhaps MS's amd64 compiler...

Comment: I cannot tell exactly why but I believe the complicated reason is due to the fact that x86 SEH is stack based and x64 SEH is table based.  Read [this](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=469) and [this](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx) for more details.  BTW, from your link, it looks like they fixed this problem in Windows 7 x64 already.  Isn't it?

Comment: Nope. The exception still doesn't get to the user-mode function who called the kernel-mode function in the first place.

Comment: @HarveyKwok The problem they *"fixed"* was the option to disable suppression of exceptions in 32-bit applications. The exceptions are still *"wrong"*, but you now have an option to **not** suppress them.

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with some sort of limitation of table-based SEH in x64: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=469 but I'm *really* curious as well... +1, this is a fantastic question.

Comment: Because the designers didn't want to (or weren't allowed to) spend the time/money to make it work.

Comment: While interesting, the question does not address a practical programming issue (knowing the answer does not affect how you write code), so I marked it off topic.

Comment: @RaymondChen Depends on the code you write; not all code is user-mode applications, or kernel-mode drivers.

Comment: I can't think of a class of code that would change based on the answer to this question. Unless you happen to work on the Windows kernel team and are trying to remove this limitation yourself.

Comment: @RaymondChen Stack Overflow for ReactOS developers :)

Comment: @RaymondChen: first time I've ever strongly disagreed with you. :)  But knowing that exceptions can get "swallowed" does change how my team writes code.  We moved our try-catch blocks closer to where exceptions are thrown, and handle our errors differently. (one could make a case that we shoulda done it that way to begin with.... but we are not as talented as RaymondChen. :) )

Comment: @abelenky knowing that it happens definitely affects how you write code. Knowing *why* it happens does not.

Comment: Knowing why it happens makes me a better programmer. If i can understand the why, I can take that knowledge and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm the developer who wrote this Hotfix a loooooooong time ago as well as the blog post. The main reason is that the full register file isn't always captured when you transition into kernel space, for performance reasons.

If you make a normal syscall, the x64 [Application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI) only requires you to preserve [the non-volatile registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx) (similar to making a normal function call). However, correctly unwinding the exception requires you to have **all** the registers, so it's not possible. Basically, this was a choice between perf in a critical scenario (i.e. a scenario that potentially happens thousands of times per second) vs. 100% correctly handling a pathological scenario (a crash).

### Bonus Reading

- [Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)
- [x86 Software Conventions - Register Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx)

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me. x86 and x64 ABIs both have caller-save/volatile registers, so there's no difference there. Unwinding doesn't require knowing the values of all registers, only the ones that aren't dead, and you'll have a bad time even in normal execution if you don't save those. Nothing in this answer seems specific to kernel-user transitions or 64-bit code, so I'm still mystified as to what special feature of that combination makes exception handling more difficult.

Comment: @benrg The problem is, to unwind exceptions you need *all* registers, not just non-volatile ones

Comment: You said that in the original answer, but why is it true? What is in those registers that's needed for unwinding and not for any other purpose?

Comment: I don't remember! But it's definitely true

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you're misremembering, unless you or someone can explain how it's even theoretically possible for that to be true. It is true that exception handling can require saving more registers in the sense that there are extra dependencies in the control flow graph that affect liveness analysis and possibly register allocation. Microsoft might have decided that they don't want that overhead in the 64-bit kernel. That isn't consistent with what you wrote since it's unrelated to the architecture or ABI, but it's something you might plausibly misremember as ABI-related.

Comment: @benrg: Any chance this is related to the use (and hence saving) of XMM registers in AMD64, rather than the general-purpose registers?

Answer (score 10):

A very good question.

I can give a hint of why "propagating" an exception across kernel-user boundary is somewhat problematic.

Citation from your question:

> Why can't 64-bit Windows unwind the stack during an exception, if **the stack crosses the kernel boundary** - when 32-bit Windows can?

The reason is very simple: There's no such a thing as "stack crosses kernel boundary". Calling a kernel-mode function is by no means comparable to a standard function call. It has nothing to do with the call stack actually. As you probably know, kernel-mode memory is simply inaccessible from the user mode.

Invoking a kernel-mode function (aka *syscall*) is implemented by triggering a software interrupt (or a similar mechanism). A user-mode code puts some values into registers (that identify the needed kernel-mode service) and invokes a CPU instruction (such as `sysenter`) which transfers the CPU into kernel-mode and passes the control to the OS.

Then there's a kernel-mode code that handles the requested syscall. It runs in a separate kernel-mode stack (that has nothing to do with the user-mode stack). After the request was handled - the control is returned to the user-mode code. Depending on the specific syscall the user-mode return address may be the one that invoked the kernel-mode transaction, as well as it may be different address.

Sometimes you call a kernel-mode function that "in the middle" should invoke a user-mode call. It may look like a call stack consisting of a user-kernel-user code, but it's just an **emulation**. In such a case the kernel-mode code transfers the control to a user-mode code which wraps your user-mode function. This wrapper code calls your function, and immediately upon its return triggers a kernel-mode transaction.

Now, if the user mode code "invoked from the kernelmode" raises an exception - this is what should happen:

1. The wrapper user-mode code handles the SEH exception (i.e. stops its propagation, but doesn't perform the stack unwinding yet).
2. Passes the control to kernel-mode (OS), as in a normal program flow case.
3. Kenrel-mode code responds appropriately. It finishes the requested service. Depending on whether there was a user-mode exception - the processing may be different.
4. Upon return to user-mode - the kernel-mode code may specify if there was a nested exception. In case of an exception the stack is not restored to its original state (since there was no unwinding yet).
5. User-mode code checks if there was such an exception. If it was - the call stack is forged to include the nested user-mode call, and the exception propagates.

So that exception that crosses kernel-user boundary is an **emulation**. There's no such a thing natively.

Comment: What is confusing is that Microsoft solved all that in 1993 when they created Windows NT. Although your answer does give a nice overview of user-kernel mode call transitions.

Comment: I mean, let's not go crazy, sysenter/sysexit and call/ret to a fixed address aren't orders of magnitude different. It really is just code all the way down. You're right that if you want to unwind the full stack, you must special-case the transition points