# How to determine wheter code is running in the context of a kernel callback?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception, 64-bit

We know the case of [disappearing exceptions in Win7 x64](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/) and several workarounds, e.g. mentioned in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a). ([Backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376795/why-cant-64-bit-windows-unwind-user-kernel-user-exceptions))

One workaround is not to place code in methods that have been called, directly or indirectly, from kernel callbacks. However, this affects several events and methods, and in general it is not documented whether a method gets called from a kernel callback.

Is there a way to see this, e.g. in the call stack?

(Note: I already tried to throw an exception and see what the debugger will do. This will work most of the time, but not always, e.g. an exception in WPF’s Window.OnClosing will never trigger the debugger. Thus, I’m looking for a more reliable way.)

Comment: No, there is no good way to tell other than working from known events that have this problem.  Changing the EXE project's Target platform setting to AnyCPU is a very simple workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks! But why is AnyCPU a workaround? I see the same behaviour with 32- and 64-bit processes as long as the OS is 64 bit. (I'm using VS2010 and VS2012 on Win7.)

Comment: Hmm, no, this a problem that's induced by the wow64 emulation layer.  It doesn't exist in a 64-bit process.  I'd work from the assumption that whatever problem you have is not actually that duck.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry, "I see the same behaviour" is wrong. Correct is: "Exceptions seem to be swallowed with 32- and 64-bit processes.". I just tried it once again: New WinForms app, override `OnLoad`, add `throw null`. On Win7 x64: 32-bit process: The exceptions seems to disappear. 64-bit process: the debugger does not stop, but App Compat Assistant starts. I don't remember exactly, but I think on XP, the debugger always stopped. And I don't know whether it's the wow64 layer or not, but this is the same duck, isn't it???

Comment: It quacks like that duck.  But I've tested that exact scenario heavily back when I still had Win7 on my machine.  And know for a fact that they don't get swallowed when the process runs in 64-bit mode.  Which entirely matches the reason they get swallowed, they had a problem with the exception traversing the thunks.  I don't want to dis-believe you, maybe there have been patches delivered through Windows Update since then that alters the behavior, sounds like a long shot.  I can't test this anymore, the problem was fixed in Win8.  It is only ever a problem while debugging anyway.