# Why does Windows swallow exceptions during WM_CLOSE

Tags: winapi, exception

While trying to figure out why an app I'm working on wouldn't close I realized it was throwing an exception in its `WM_CLOSE` handler.  However instead of the app crashing (as it should), the exception gets silently ignored.

To make sure there wasn't something else going on, I created a new C++ Win32 app in Visual Studio and added this:

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    (*(int*)NULL) = 0;
    break;
```

Same thing:  no crash, just a first chance exception in the debug log.  If I add the same code to a `WM_COMMAND` handler it crashes as expected.

So I'm curious: what's so special about `WM_CLOSE` that Windows deems exceptions thrown by it should be swallowed?

(BTW: this is on Windows 7 x64, running x86 program)

Comment: There's nothing inherently special about `WM_CLOSE`. Unhandled exceptions in your `WndProc` callback always get silently ignored, by calling `WndProc` under a `__try`/`__except` handler. This is the only safe implementation, since [when you transfer control across stack frames, all the frames in between need to be in on the joke](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/10/10347674.aspx).

Comment: By default WindoWProcedure calls destroy window to destroy the window. This could be a reason, that any exceptions are then redirected to "/dev/null":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @IInspectable, I don't think Raymond Chen says the `WndProc` callback is protected in his article. It actually looks like he's saying the opposite: `As a result of this overall mindset, Win32 code doesn't worry too much about recovering from exceptions. If an exception happens, then it means your process is already toast and there's no point trying to fix it`. In addition, if the callback was protected then a NULL pointer dereference would not crash in a `WM_COMMAND` handler either.

Comment: I read it as "you can't throw exceptions across stack frames that are not in your control" - wndproc is one of them as its a call back, so they get "lost" as it can't propagate back to your message loop function.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not aware that calls to WndProc are called in __try/__except.  Certainly unhandled exceptions don't always get silently ignored - they should cause the app to terminate.  Where's the transfer across stack frames?

Comment: @icbytes it's not related to the window being destroyed - the exception occurs before DefWindowProc is called, the window isn't destroyed and the app continues to run.

Comment: Did You execute it ONLY in visual studio or also as standalone application ?

Comment: @paulm the exception doesn't need to be propagated back to the message loop.  There's no apparent reason for it to be lost/swallowed though.

Comment: The message pump is your code, it calls MS code, which calls your code (window proc) if window proc throws you expect it to end up back at message pump. It won't, because MS code won't pass it on.

Comment: @Brad If you would rather not have your exceptions swallowed you need to provide a Win7-compatible manifest with your application, and compile for 64-bit. Otherwise the 'old' Win2k3 behavior is in effect, which swallows exceptions.

Comment: Just to be clear this isn't really a problem for my app. I'm just curious why the behavior would be different for WM_CLOSE compared to most other messages eg: WM_COMMAND.

Comment: @icbytes both - same behavior

Comment: @paulm I don't expect it to be thrown back to the message loop.  I expect it to terminate the app like any other exception normally does.

Comment: Then You should stick to paulm's answer. The "transfer" between stackframes sounds logical in this case, because the wndproc in Your program and the windows message pump define both two stack frames, though, if You except a try-catch error, code it down and throw another windows messsage EITHER IN try, then in catch and inspect the behaviour.

Comment: @IInspectable Unless there's a manifest setting that controls the behavior for different window messages, not sure how the manifest is related to this.  Exceptions in WM_CLOSE are swallowed, exceptions in WM_COMMAND terminate the app.

Comment: What I also could think of is, that WM_CLOSE is harder defined then WM_COMMAND. The WM_CLOSE message could be of a type, which is not that much checked by the usual coder, as WM_COMMAND might be, and therefore handles WM_CLOSE a little bit more "loose". But now my ideas reached the end. I do not have other explanations.

Comment: @paulm "It won't, because MS code won't pass it on."  Not sure what you mean by this.  In fact if I wrap DispatchMessage in a try-except, exceptions thrown by wndproc _are_ propagated up to the message loop function. (unless they're thrown in a handler for WM_CLOSE).

Comment: This is documented well in the MSDN article for [WindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You are seeing #1 behavior.  Be careful with the PCA, that OK button looks *way* too tempting.  Removing the appcompat shim requires editing the registry.  Or renaming your EXE :)

Comment: @Brad Having a valid Windows 7 manifest is enough to change the behavior. This is detailed in [The case of the disappearing OnLoad exception](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/). I should have been more precise: Not all exceptions are swallowed by default, but only those where the `WndProc` is the user-mode callback of a kernel function (e.g. `WM_CREATE`/`WM_NCCREATE` as a result of calling `CreateWindow`).

Comment: Yep, it was behaviour #1 in the doco for WindowProc.  Interestingly just rebuilding for x64 didn't fix it - I needed to also rename the executable as mentioned by @HansPassant.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, WM_CLOSE crashes for me. I'm on 32-bit Win7, though.

Comment: Tried it on XP 32-bit, it crashes there, too.

Comment: It is visual studio which eats exceptions in the window proc, not windows. I normally use Borland C and are used to the "luxury" the application crashes if an exception happens anywhere in the application. Now to make a x64 build I compile the code in Visual Studio and it is annoying the message processing is simply canceled when there is a problem instead of a crash of the application. I am trying to figure out how to configure VC so it crashes.

UPDATE: oh, it is windows x64, not VC....

Comment: UPDATE 2: and only in XP, in Windows 10 the application is exited

Answer (score 2):

That exceptions be swallowed by a `WindowProc` on Win 64 is expected behavior. ([See docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

**Also** see the better explanations on [Paul Betts'](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/) blog, especially his note

> ### How come this doesn’t happen all the time?
>
> Here’s why this seems to happen only on certain window messages –
>   remember that window messages can originate from different sources,
>   anyone(*) can queue a message to a window. However, certain window
>   messages are directly sent via win32k.sys (the most notable one being
>   WM_CREATE) as a direct synchronous result of a user-mode call.

seems to shed some light on this question.

[Random ASCII also](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/when-even-crashing-doesnt-work/) has some good explanation on all this kernel-mode-ex-swallowing behavior:

> ### Failure to stop at all
>
> An equally disturbing problem was introduced some years ago with
>   64-bit Windows and it causes some crashes to be silently ignored.
>
> Structured exception ... relies on being able to unwind the stack
>   (without or without calling destructors) in order to transfer
>   execution from where an exception occurs to a catch/__except block.
>
> The introduction of 64-bit Windows complicated this. On 64-bit Windows
>   **it is impossible to unwind the stack across the kernel boundary.** That is, if ... an exception is thrown in the callback that is
>   supposed to be handled on the other side of the kernel boundary, then
>   Windows cannot handle this.
>
> This may seem a bit esoteric and unlikely – writing kernel callbacks
>   seems like a rare activity – but it’s actually quite common. In
>   particular, a **WindowProc** is a callback, and it **is often** called by
>   the kernel, ...

And as a bonus: See [here on SO on the why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376795/why-cant-64-bit-windows-unwind-user-kernel-user-exceptions).

Comment: I think it is horrible and shocking that Windows silently swallows exceptions - that Windows silently ignores crashes.

The Raymond Chen article points out the danger of having exceptions handled without everybody being in on the joke which makes it weirder yet that Windows does that.

BTW, I'm the author of the Random ASCII article linked in this answer.

Comment: @BruceDawson - I do agree about horrible, whereas after all I've been through wrt. Windows crash handling (from XP onwards), I'm not so sure I find much shocking anymore. :-) ... And thanks for Random ASCII - always great resources there!